SharePoint list custom PowerApps form variable not updated
I have modified a SharePoint list form with PowerApps and want to set a variable with the currently loaded listitem.
I tried to set it in the "App.OnStart" and also "FormScreen1.OnVisible" but it is not getting updated correctly:
Set(_item; SharePointIntegration.Selected);;

The first listitem I load is shown correctly, but the variable is not getting updated if I switch the listitems. How can I set the variable on each listitem I load?

Instead of using App.OnStart or FormScreen1.OnVisible, you can try setting the variable in the OnSelect property of the gallery or form control that displays the list items. This ensures the variable is updated each time a new item is selected.
1,Set the variable in the gallery’s OnSelect property:
Set(_item, ThisItem)

2,Ensure the form is connected to the variable:
In your form control, set the Item property to _item.
This way, every time you select a different item in the gallery, the _item variable will be updated with the currently selected item.
